# One sample t-Test for proportional data

Tags: anova, t-test, data-transformation, proportion

I have 4 group of fish (n=28 per group). I have measured the amount of time that a fish in each group spent exploring two different objects  (A and B) in a squared shape tank. Then I have calculated an exploration index as: time spent with A/time spent with B + time spent with A.

Now I have some proportional data and I am going to test whether a fish spent time with A more than chance level (0.5) to see if they have a preference for object A. To see if there is a difference between exploration ratios and chance level, I am gonna run one sample t-test. However, as I read some papers, I think I should do arcsin transformation (arcsine square root transformation) for my data. However, when I transform my data and run one-sample t-test I get wired results. For example, my raw exploration ratios show that they are below chance level (mean: 0.322 and SD:0.12) while after transformation of data I see that the ratio are now higher than chance level. I am really confused and I do not now how I should treat with my data. I would really appreciate it if you can advise me.

Comment: What is the role of the four groups? Is a ratio of 0.2 equally relevant no matter how much/little time is spent?

Comment: I have four groups of fish. First I am gonna test that within each group there is a significant preference for object A. To do so I am gonna test whether or not they spend more time with A object than chance! Second off, I am gonna test if there is any difference between groups in exploration of A object. In fact, the ratio is an index which show fish preference for either objects!

Comment: Regarding the first part of the comment: This testing strategy will need a proper multiple testing approach. Regarding the second one I meant the following: Is it similar if (1) a fish looks 1 second at A and 4 seconds at B or (2) a fish looks 1 minute at A and 4 minutes at B? They have the same ratio.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the arcsine tranformation is appropriate when
you're comparing your exploration indexes (proportions) against
a hypothetical value.

Suppose you have data as follows, which may be somewhat similar to those you describe in your Question.

```
x
 [1] 0.4592 0.2577 0.1213 0.4931 0.1618 0.4592
 [7] 0.2216 0.4176 0.1370 0.2855 0.2973 0.6395
[13] 0.1795 0.3708 0.3844 0.3936 0.4856 0.1087
[19] 0.2843 0.3793 0.5034 0.4836 0.2183 0.2581
[25] 0.1053
summary(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1053  0.2183  0.2973  0.3242  0.4592  0.6395 
[1] 0.1475581  # SD
```

Then you can do a one-sample Wilcoxon (signed rank) test
to see if the population median is below $0.5.$ The result (for my
data) is that the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 0.5$
is rejected in favor of the alternative $H_a: \mu < 0.5.$ (Results from R.)

```
wilcox.test(x, mu = .5, alt="less")

    Wilcoxon signed rank test 
    with continuity correction

data:  x
V = 13, p-value = 3.045e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location is less than 0.5

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(x, mu = 0.5, alt = "less") :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Unless the P-value is very near $0.05$ you should not be concerned
about the warning message for a sample as large as $n = 25.$

Then when you get around to comparing the four groups with each other,
you can use a Kruskal-Wallis nonparametric test.

*Note:* I am not surprised you got strange results with the 'arcsine'
transformation. The transformed data can easily be above $0.5.$

```
y = asin(sqrt(x));  mean(y)
[1] 0.5955257
```

The usual purpose of this transformation is to 'stabilize' variances
in data that arise from binomial proportions, so that variances will
not be seriously unequal in a two-sample t test or a one-way ANOVA.

If you were doing a one-sample t test, I see no
point in doing the arcsine transformation. If you are comparing two
groups with a t test or several groups with a one-way ANOVA, you could
use the Welch versions of these procedures, which do not assume
equal variances. It might be OK for you to use such tests with your
data. The reason I suggested nonparametric Wilcoxon and Kruskal-Wallis
procedures is that there is no reason to assume your ratios are normally
distributed, and I have not seen your actual data.

Comment: Many thanks for such comprehensive explanation. It was absolutely helpful.